# Icecast/Ezstream showing wrong song title in VLC media player

Tags: icecast

I have a live music stream [here](http://www.xtremeirc.net:8000/stream). I use Icecast and Ezstream to produce the steam.

My problem is that, when using VLC media player (or any other player), **all** song titles are prefixed with **Led Zeppelin**. Since neither of the config files `(/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml and ezstream_mp3.xml)` contain the words **Led Zeppelin** in them, I won't paste them unless asked to.

I have abt 600 titles that are randomly played, and several of those are indeed **Led Zeppelin**. Does anyone know what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Without more information, it's hard to help you narrow this down.  I suspect though that your files are indeed tagged with Led Zeppelin.  In any case, start by running a packet capture on the interface between Ezstream and Icecast to determine which has the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i got this same problem.
Probably related to some facts found from the internet that ezstream does support only id3v1. (not confirmed). This causes the case when "the next song" has the same title as the previous one.
You can't fix this from the Icecast admin panel, as based on my experience.